# How to downplay non-essentials in HTML file from Microsoft Steps Recorder? to let others focus on essential info

Tags: html, windows, ms-word, formatting, problem-steps-recorder

Microsoft Community Expert advises following

> I save and download as a .mht or html file from Steps Recorder app and
> open it with Microsoft Edge. Click "Control" + "U" on the keyboard to
> view the HTML code on notepad. Find or replace all codes regarding
> 'time', then save as a new HTML file.

My workaround seems simpler (using Word Find and Replace); is there a better way?

```
\: \(*\)
```

Screenshot as follows
[Word Find and Replace Dates and Time in HTML file of Microsoft Steps Recorder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vdeyQ.gif)

Answer (score 0):

After waiting for a week, I decided to post my own solution as shown in my re-edited post. It allows me to replace with smaller Font to de-emphasize Date and Time information for each line prefixed with "Step "